# Unable to transfer large .csv row count to Excel 2007

Tags: csv, vbscript, excel-2007, export-to-excel, file-format

I've been using the below VBScript code snippet to move an hourly .csv drop to an Excel file. It works like clockwork except recently the .csv crossed the 65536 row limitation. The machine is flooded with popups from Compatibility Checker and then I realized it was using Excel 2003 even through Excel 2007 is installed. Not sure why this happens even when **Excel.Application.12** object is explicitly invoked:

```
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application.12")
With oExcel
    .DefaultSaveFormat=51
    .Workbooks.Open sourceFile
    .Sheets(1).Columns("A").TextToColumns .Range("A1"), xlDelimited, , , , True
    .ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs outputFile, xlNormal
    .Quit
End With
```

How do I make this script pull a row count greater than 65536 to be imported into Excel 2007 without the Compatibility Checker prompt, while preserving all source rows?

Some additional information:

1. Brand new machine
2. Running Windows 7 x64 bit OS
3. There is only one version of Office installed: Office 2007

Comment: Just added additional information. No it's not multi-version, only Office 2007 is installed

Comment: Not a problem. Well, I tried with and without default format and using the .xlsx extension. Neither helped

Comment: Added the key under Excel instead of Word, no dice. This is nuts! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `fileformat:=51` as advised by [Ron de Bruin](http://www.rondebruin.nl/saveas.htm).

Below extracted from an edit by OP to the Question:

> Below change worked!:
>
> ```
>  Dim oExcel  
>  Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application.12")  
>  With oExcel  
>     .DefaultSaveFormat=51  
>     .Workbooks.Open sourceFile  
>     .Sheets(1).Columns("A").TextToColumns .Range("A1"), xlDelimited, , , , True  
>     .ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs outputFile, 51  
>     .Quit  
>  End With
> ```
>
> Also, make sure the file extension is .xlsx.

Comment: thanks for your persistence. I changed the SaveAs to outputFile, 51 and it worked!